# How does one choose a column in CSV file for tokenization with python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have loaded a data set (CSV-File) which has a column `project description`
I need to load the words/sentences in this column for tokenzation. I tried the following code:

```
token = word_tokenize('school_state')
```

But that does not work and *Behaviour* happens instead.

Comment: Please provide the full code sample to understand your query better.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you use Pandas to load CSV? Also, note that 'school_state' is a string and will be tokenized as ['school_state'].

Comment: Yes I used pandas to load CSV . Please tell what would be next step .....